# Can I use a 2x6 beam stretched across a few of these roof rafters to support a hammock?

Tags: ceiling, framing, safety

I want to hang a large hammock in my reading room. It used to be an open-air carport structure and so the construction is fairly lightweight. Here're some pictures of the ceiling/roof in question pre-drywall.

If I take a 2x4 or 2x6 and span several of the rafters, would it be safe to hang the hammock from the center of the 2x6?

Alternatively, would it be better to mount the hammock directly to the center roof beam (4x6?)?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be OK, but another alternative would be to add another rafter just for the hammock.  That might look a little better, too.

Answer (score 0):

assuming everything is in good structural shape (looks okay in the photo), i would think its good to go.  an alternative would be to hang the hammock off of two eyebolts through the middle of the rafters.  that way, two rafters are taking the load directly.

Comment: I like the idea of spreading the load for the hammock in red line only 1 support where I live hammocks are 2 points of support separated by 7 to 9 feet . From what I can see your plan will work well for even a big guy like me +250 lb